# I have searched for hours, please can somene tell me why my code won't run, before i throw my pc at the wall

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int flushmuch(int yes, int flush[])
{
        if(flush == yes)
        {
        printf("well done, it went down");
        }
        else
        {
        printf("get the plunger!");
        }
}

int main()
{
int theluckyone;
int threeturd[] = {1, 2, 3};

printf("did pick a letter between one, two, and three to see if your turds have been flushed \n");
scanf("%d", &theluckyone);

int flushmuch(theluchyone, threeturd[1]);

return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to be a guessing game where the user guesses a number and if the player is correct the turd flushes down. Uncanny I know, it was supposed to be something quick just to learn and get some practice before I make snake game.

Comment: First does your code compile? Second, if it doesn't compile what error message do you get? What does this line "if(flush == yes)" mean to you? `flush` is an array and `yes` is a single integer.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `int flushmuch(theluchyone, threeturd[1]);` won't compile.

Comment: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token
   23 | int flushmuch(thelukhyone, threeturd[1]);
      |                                     ^
      |                                     )

Comment: In addition to the other errors pointed out, `int flushmuch(theluchyone, threeturd[1]);` is a function declaration, not a function call. Drop the `int` then work on fixing the other errors. Compiler warnings should be heeded.

Answer (score 1):

1. flushmuch() doesn't return anything. Either change to void or return
2. fix typos in theluckyone, theluchyone
3. int flushmuch. Why int?
4. here your are passing second element from threeturd[1], but in function you expect. int flush[] . either pass "threeturd" or change function arguent to  int flush

all I could spot. there is probably more.